# How to make the images come in a single row

Tags: html, css

I have the below code, I want my images to be in a single row and in the centre. Please suggest something. I have tried a row and column with float properties, but it did not work. I want to add this to my website.

Also, I was wondering how can I use it as a JScript instead of exposing the whole code??

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;  
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;

}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-user:hover {
  color: #fff;
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
  <a href="#" class="icon" title="User Profile">
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
  <a href="#" class="icon" title="User Profile">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
add those two divs with class `container` into one div and then use `flexbox` css property to that div like this

HTML code:

```
<div.main> <div.container>...</div> <div.container>...</div> </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.main {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: space-around; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

and that's it, try this out and let me know.

Comment: the images are inline but the hover effect is all distorted :(.

Comment: I modified the answer. Add css property `text-align: center` to main div and you are good to go. Try it out and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Here to help... ✌

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have used Flexbox before but if you don't know about it, it's a pretty cool styling CSS tool. No script import needed. It's awesome!

If instead of wrapping in 2 `container` classes, you can wrap in one and achieve the desired effect quickly by doing something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="#" class="icon" title="User Profile">
      <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </a>
  </div>


  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="#" class="icon" title="User Profile">
      <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and with your CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;              // make it a single row
  justify-content: center;    // center horizontally
  align-items: center;        // center vertically
  height: 100px;    // if you want to fix a height
  width: 100px;     // if you want to fix a width
}
```

Please let me know if it works or if you have any question :) Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that. The images are aligned and in the same row. But the hover effect is all out of place